# Python MemoryError: Could not allocate enough memory

Tags: python, data-science, decision-tree

I'm trying to use machine learning algorithms to establish a model relating my target output variable to two separate input variables and as I run model.fit(X, Y) I get a memory error that says it couldn't allocate 5.7GB, which seems odd considering that I have 8GB of ram and no other programs/windows open at the same time as pycharm.

Edit: I am using 64 bit python, which as I understand should automatically allocate as much memory as necessary

Here's the last few lines of the error message after retrying, this time it couldn't allocate even 4GB:

```
File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 145, in sklearn.tree._tree.DepthFirstTreeBuilder.build
  File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 243, in sklearn.tree._tree.DepthFirstTreeBuilder.build
  File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 740, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree._add_node
  File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 712, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree._resize_c
  File "sklearn\tree\_utils.pyx", line 41, in sklearn.tree._utils.safe_realloc
MemoryError: could not allocate 4062707712 bytes
```

Comment: Check if you use 64-bit python. Turn off web browsers.

Comment: What's the exact error message ?

Comment: Did you check out the memory usage right before you run the code? You can check it by task manager. Make sure you do have enough memory for python to allocate at that moment, but not just simply compare with the 8GB. That is all you have, but not the moment you can allocate.

Comment: Elaborate question with which model you try to build? what is the file size?